# How to create the equivalent of a COUNTIF Excel function in R which will work for a list of nums

Tags: r, iteration, counting, countif

I have a list which looks like this:

```
> str(my_list)
List of 20000
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 0.667
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 0.667
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
```

.
.
.

And I want to create an lapply that will tell me how many of the elements of my list are < 1, which is a logical condition of course. To me, this sounds like something I could probably do rather easily just using a COUNTIF function in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `list` having each element of length 1, just `unlist` it to a vector and get the `sum` of logical vector (`< 1`) will give the count of the number of list elements with less than 1

```
sum(unlist(my_list) < 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

If the list element have length > 1, we may have to either loop over the list with `sapply`, create a logical vector, and maybe wrap with `any` or `all` (if the intention is to find any element less than 1 or all elements)

```
sum(sapply(my_list, \(x) any(x < 1, na.rm = TRUE)))
```