# How to create the equivalent of an AND Excel function to assess the equivalent of two Excel COUNTIF functions, but in R instead

Tags: r, excel, counting, countif

This question is based on the answer I got to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75038163/how-to-create-the-equivalent-of-a-countif-excel-function-in-r-which-will-work-fo) I asked on here. The question is, how can I do what I could do in Excel using its AND function in the following manner (warning, I am likely going to confuse some of you here because I am just going to put the two working R equivalents of COUNTIFs I already have working as the two arguments in Excel's AND function):

```
AND(sum(unlist(BM1_TPRs) < 1, na.rm = TRUE),  sum(FPRs == 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Either that, or, the simplified version I figured out myself after implementing the previous answer:

```
TPRs <- unlist(BM1_TPRs)
num_Under <- sum(TPRs < 1, na.rm = TRUE)

FPRs <- unlist(BM1_FPRs)
num_null_FPR <- sum(FPRs == 0, na.rm = TRUE)

AND(num_Under, num_null_FPR)
```

Again, BM1_TPRs and BM1_FPRs are just lists with 20k numeric elements, all of which are within the range [0, 1]. So, my actual goal here is to count how many times both the TPR is less than 1 and the FPR is 1.

I have tried this:

```
nUnder = intersect((TPRs < 1), (FPRs == 0))
```

But it does not work at all.

Comment: Do you want `sum( (TPRs <1) & (FPRs == 0) )` ? This is an element-wise comparison -- the ith element of TPRs is less than 1 AND the ith element of FPRs == 0, summed over all i.

Comment: @MartinMorgan wow, holy moly, yes I do want that cuz it works

Comment: If you're moving from Excel to R it can be counterintuitive. I recommend downloading the [swirl](https://github.com/swirldev/swirl) package, an interactive set of lessons for R, and doing lesson 8, Boolean logic. Once you get a sense of how R interprets logical vectors and operators these questions quickly go from mystifying to straightforward. This is a recommendation not spam - I think it's a great package for learning the language but have no association with it.

Comment: @SamR I am already well into my transition actually, but for some reason, even at this point, I am still not competent in using IFs in R or functions occasionally (especially within apply functions), and SUMIF & COUNTIF just seem infinitely more intuitive to me for whatever reason.

Comment: That's where one problem exists: you cannot think of using R's `if` function when trying to mimic Excel's `SUMIF`/`COUNTIF`; you may be closer to think of `ifelse` which handles logical vectors (0 or more), you may do better to think of `SUMIF` as `SUM(val[condition])` and `COUNTIF` as `SUM(condition)`. Looking at it that way, you can create `condition <- `TPRs < 1 & FPRs == 0`, look at the vector, then `sum` (of some variable based on the true/false in the vector, SUMIF) or `sum` the condition vector itself (COUNTIF).